# Result on a finite dimensional vector space and its subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb R$ and $W$ be a subspace of $V$. Let $T$ be an endomorphism on $V$ and $W \bigcap T(W) \neq\{0\}$. Then $T$ be a linear automorphism on $V\iff$

1. $W = V$
2. $\dim(W)\lt \frac{1}{2}\dim(V)$
3. $\dim(W)= \frac{1}{2}\dim(V)$
4. $\dim(W)\gt \frac{1}{2}\dim(V)$

I can solve this question by contradiction. Take $V=\mathbb R^3$ , $W=(x, y, 0)$ and $T(x, y, z) =(x, y, z) $ and option 1,2,3 discarded. But I can't prove this result. Please help me. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is $\;T\;$ supposed to be an endomorphism of $\;V\;$ ...or *what*?

Comment: T is automorphism and hence endomorphism

Comment: Then write thatin the body of the question, please.

Comment: Its already given in the question that T is automorphism

Comment: I can't see it is given. It is asked to *prove* that $\;T\;$ is a linear automorphis if and only if....etc. So to begin with... *what is* $\;T\;$ **anyway** ? Is it just a function $\;T:V\to T\;$ ??

Comment: I want to prove dim(W) >1/2 times dim(V) and conversly

Comment: Ok. I understand your points

Comment: The question continues to be pretty unclear...at least to me.

Comment: I correct the question now. Please see now

Comment: What will happen if you take $V = \Bbb R^3,$ $W = \{(x,0,0)\ |\ x \in \Bbb R \} \subseteq V$ and take $T = \text {Id}\ $?

Comment: I don't think any option is true in the general case...

Comment: @Debu the problem is wrong as suggested by Don.

Comment: I understand now. The given question was wrong